# How to design a way to provide an implementation in Scala

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I am designing a framework in scala. This framework will have 3 traits: A, B and C. In order to use it, the developer will extend those traits and provide an implementation. Then, he will call an execute() function which will use the implementations.

The problem is: I wont pass any instance to the execute function. That function should use the implementations provided as it needs them. I dont know how to do this.

My first idea was to create a class (which will contain that function) and it will receive as parameter 3 factory methods to create instances of those classes. The code would be something like this:

```
trait Abs{def f():Int}

case class Concr extends Abs{def f():Int = 8}    

case class Manager[A <: Abs](val factory: () => A){def exec():Int = {factory().f()}}

Manager[Concr]({() => Concr()}).exec() //It evaluates 8
```

The problem of this solution is it is dirty, as in the manager you have to refer to the factory every time you want to create an instance and I was trying to find a better way.

Comment: I am confused. What stops you from just calling `Concr().f()`?

Comment: Well, I can not do that because Concr is the implementation provided by the developer. So in my framework I will only have the Abs trait with the abstract functions. So, when I am writing the code I dont have access to that class and I want to find a way to tell the framework: listen, this is my implementation that I want to use (Concr). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then how are you going to tell the framework which implementation you are going to use? There must be some ways to identify each implementation. By name or by developer etc.

Comment: Yes exactly. What I am asking here is precisely which is the best way to do that :)

Comment: How did you "obtain" the implementation? I could not figure out the exact problem. If your framework knows the implementation extends `Abs` then just call `f()` on that object.

Answer (score 0):

> it is dirty, as in the manager you have to refer to the factory every time you want to create an instance

And why is that a problem? You have to write `factory()` *exactly* where you would write `Concr()` if you somehow magically could refer to it. This makes the code cleaner if anything.

You can make the name cleaner (e.g. `A` or `makeA` instead of `factory`) and/or use by-name parameter (write `factory: => A` and access it as just `factory` in the body).